# Referencing format manually

Tags: cross-referencing

Someone could help me, please?

I do referencing, but manually, I don't use package. I want to format just some pages of References, for each paragraph (each reference): noindent for the first line, and parindent (for example 1cm) from the second line to the end like in the photo.[image]

```
\newpage

\begin{center}
\huge\bfseries{References}
\end{center}

ABC, A., Bekaert, G., 2002. “International Asset Allocation with Regime Shifts”. \textit{The QBCQSFD qsFQSReqsdfqsqfsdfqvsdf sdfqsiew of Fiqsdfqsdf nancial Studies} 15, 1125432137-1183217.

Aqsdfqsdfng, A., Chqsdfeqsfdnqsdf, J., 2002. “Asymmeqsdfdqsftric correqsdfqsdfqslations of eqdsfqsdfquity portqsdfqsdfqsfolios”. \textit{Jourqsdfqsdfnal of Finaqsdfqsdfqsfncial Econqsdfqsdfqsdfomics} 63, 44321-494.
```

Comment: could you add a compilable `MWE`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. :(

Comment: pleass have a look here: http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want `\parindent`, but `\hangindent` (this uses an environment to make the manual insertion of paragraph breaks optional).

[image: references]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{references}{\par
    \newcommand\newreference{\par\noindent\hangindent=1cm\hangafter=1}
}{\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\huge\bfseries{References}
\end{center}

\begin{references}
\newreference Ang, A., Bekaert, G., 2002. “International Asset Allocation with Regime Shifts”. \textit{The Review of Financial Studies} 15, 1137-1187.

\newreference Ang, A., Chen, J., 2002. “Asymmetric correlations of equity portfolios”. \textit{Journal of Financial Economics} 63, 443-494.

\newreference Anyfantaki, S., Avarnitis, S., Tapologlou, N., 2018. “Diversification, Integration and Cryptocurrency Market”. \textit{Working paper, Athens University of Business and Economics}. 

\newreference Arditti, F.D., 1975. “Skewness and Investors' Decisions: A Reply”. \textit{Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis} 10, 173-176.

\newreference Arouri, M.E.H, Hammoudeh, S., Lahiani, A., Nguyen, D.K 2012. “Long memory and structural breaks in modeling the return and volatility dynamics of precious metals”. \textit{The Quarterly Review of Economics and Finance} 52, 207-218.

\newreference Arvanitis, S., Hallam, M., Post, T., Topaloglou, N., 2018. “Stochastic Spanning”.  \textit{Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics (forthcoming)}.
\end{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DgPHAM If this solved your problem, consider accepting this answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the voting buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Surely, i know that somebody will help you in a better way than this.  I think meanwhile you can try this

```
    \hspace{.4cm}\begin{minipage}[c]{.95\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{-1cm}
Ang, A., Bekaert, G., 2002. “International Asset Allocation with Regime Shifts”. \textit{The Review of Financial Studies} 15, 1137-1187.

Ang, A., Chen, J., 2002. “Asymmetric correlations of equity portfolios”. \textit{Journal of Financial Economics} 63, 443-494.

Anyfantaki, S., Avarnitis, S., Tapologlou, N., 2018. “Diversification, Integration and Cryptocurrency Market”. \textit{Working paper, Athens University of Business and Economics}. 

Arditti, F.D., 1975. “Skewness and Investors' Decisions: A Reply”. \textit{Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis} 10, 173-176.

Arouri, M.E.H, Hammoudeh, S., Lahiani, A., Nguyen, D.K 2012. “Long memory and structural breaks in modeling the return and volatility dynamics of precious metals”. \textit{The Quarterly Review of Economics and Finance} 52, 207-218.

Arvanitis, S., Hallam, M., Post, T., Topaloglou, N., 2018. “Stochastic Spanning”.  \textit{Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics (forthcoming)}. 
\end{minipage}
```

Hope this will help you atleast

Comment: Although this might give a somewhat similar result at the first glance this example might disobey the margins and has to be followed by  a paragraph break for obvious reasons. Please make it a compilable snippet explaining the caveats.